# Retorno php para o JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Preciso uma variável JS que pegar o resultado em um .load JQuery de um arquivo php.

JQuery

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "_required/sessaoCarrinho.php",
 data: {idProduto:idCampo, novaQuantidade: novaQuantidade},
 success: function(data){
    var subTotal = data;
    return false;
 }
});

alert(subTotal);              

$(".subTotal").html(subTotal.toFixed(2));
$(".totalCarrinho").html(subTotal.toFixed(2));
```

php

```
<?php
  session_start();

  $idProduto = $_POST["idProduto"];
  $novaQuantidade = $_POST["novaQuantidade"];

  require_once "../../_controlls/_conexao/Conexao.php";  
  require_once "../../_controlls/_models/Produtos.php";
  require_once "../../_controlls/_daos/ProdutosDao.php";
  require_once "../../_controlls/_util/PhpUtil.php";
  require_once "../../_controlls/_util/Carrinho.php";

  $connection = new Conexao();
  $conexao = $connection->abreConexao();  

  $produtosDao = new ProdutosDao($conexao);  
  $phpUtil = new PhpUtil();
  $carrinho = new Carrinho($produtosDao, $phpUtil);


  $novoProduto = $produtosDao->pesquisaProdutoId($_POST["idProduto"]);

  foreach ($_SESSION["carrinho"] as $key=>$produtoC) {
       if($produtoC[idProdutos] == $novoProduto->getIdProdutos()) {        
           $achou = true;
           $chave = $key;
           $estoque = $novoProduto->getEstoque();
           break;                
       }
   }

   if($achou == true) {
       if ($estoque > $_SESSION["carrinho"][$chave]["quantidade"]) {
          $_SESSION["carrinho"][$chave]["quantidade"] = $novaQuantidade;
       }
   }

   $subTotal = $carrinho->subTotal();

   echo $subTotal;

?>
```

O que estou fazendo de errado que a variável `subtotal` no `JQuery` só chega `not defined`

Já tentei também assim no php mas não deu certo

```
   $subTotal = $carrinho->subTotal();

   echo "<script>var subTotal=".$subTotal."</script>";
```

Comment: Posso estar sendo ignorante, mas tente assim =>  die(json_encode(['subTotal' => $subTotal])

Comment: Experimente o `alert(subTotal);` dentro do success do ajax

Comment: carrinho.js:28 Uncaught ReferenceError: subTotal is not defined

Comment: json_encode(['subTotal' => $subTotal] é um array. Esta dando erro na forma de colocação do array

Comment: @CarlosRocha deixei uma resposta a sua pergunta.

Comment: sim, já testei e deixei um comentário: quase lá!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Javascript:

```
function produto(data, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "_required/sessaoCarrinho.php",
            data: {idProduto: idCampo, novaQuantidade: novaQuantidade},
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (response) {
            callback(response);
        });
    }
    function getProduto(response) {
        $(".subTotal").html(response.subTotal.toFixed(2));
        $(".totalCarrinho").html(response.subTotal.toFixed(2));
    }
    produto(data,getProduto);
```

OR

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "_required/sessaoCarrinho.php",
    data: {idProduto: idCampo, novaQuantidade: novaQuantidade},
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function (response) {
    $(".subTotal").html(response.subTotal.toFixed(2));
    $(".totalCarrinho").html(response.subTotal.toFixed(2));
});
```

No PHP:

echo json_encode(array('subTotal' => $subTotal));

Comment: carrinho.js:29 Uncaught ReferenceError: subTotal is not definedsub @ carrinho.js:29onclick @ carrinho.php:149
carrinho.js:25 Object {subTotal: 509.93}.

Comment: Daí fiz abaixo do console.log(response); subTotal = response e deu indefinido

Comment: achei: subTotal = response['subTotal']; OIbrigado.

Comment: @CarlosRocha sobre o erro  **subTotal is not definedsub**, ele nunca vai retornar porque o ajax é assíncrono, ou seja, ele não vai esperar terminar o ajax para terminar de ler o código. Outra coisa, se a resposta foi útil, de um voto para me fortalecer. vlw

Comment: $(".subTotal").html(subTotal.toFixed(2)); pois é, como resolver esse problema então? Eu preciso dessa informação para exibir na label

Comment: @CarlosRocha editei a resposta, de uma olhada. Espero que lhe ajude. Outra coisa, procure no google sobre callback() no ajax.

Comment: demorei um pouco a responder pois estava tentando. e fiz exatamente isso. Mas valeu pela resposta.